# Save multiple image from camera roll to document directory crashed due to memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uiimage, nsdocumentdirectory

When i try to save more than 10 image to document directory its making crash due to memory issue.

```
 -(void) importArrayDictionary: (NSArray *) arrayDictionary ToFolder: (NSString *) folderDestination {

_requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
_requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
_requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
_requestOptions.synchronous = true;

//kch-data
dispatch_queue_t importQueue = dispatch_queue_create("importQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(importQueue, ^{





    for(PHAsset *asset in arrayDictionary){
        //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self createFileWithName: [self generateNewFileName:[self getTypeFromDictionary:asset]] Folder: folderDestination Item:asset];
        //});

    }



    //Notify delegate
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(pgDataSourceDidFinishImportingFiles:)])
            [self.delegate pgDataSourceDidFinishImportingFiles: self];
    });
});
}
```

Here is my code which i use to save. I am making 3 different size images from main image and save these images to document directory. Finally save main image to document directory. After finished saving one image, it don't release memory. I think this is the problem.

```
   -(NSString *) createFileWithName: (NSString *) name Folder: (NSString *) folder Item: (PHAsset *) aDicItem {//kch-data



__block UIImage *_imageThumb;

//
PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
[manager requestImageForAsset:aDicItem
                   targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                  contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                      options:_requestOptions
                resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
                    _imageThumb = image;

                }];

//UIImage *_imageThumb = [aDicItem objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
//Thumb110
//CGSize size = _imageThumb.size;
UIImage *thumbImage110 = [_imageThumb thumbnailImage:200 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:0 interpolationQuality: kCGInterpolationHigh];

//thumbImage110 = [_imageThumb imageWithImage:_imageThumb scaledToFillSize:size];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbImage110, 0.75) writeToFile: [self getThumbnail110PathForFilename: name] atomically:YES];

//Thumb150
UIImage *thumbImage150 = [_imageThumb thumbnailImage:200 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:0 interpolationQuality: kCGInterpolationHigh];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbImage150, 0.75) writeToFile: [self getThumbnail150PathForFilename: name] atomically:YES];
NSString *filePath;
NSString *folderPath = [self.itmesDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: folder];
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:FAKE_MODE]){
    folderPath = [self.fakeDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: folder];
}
filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: name];


NSCharacterSet *chss = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"'#%^&{}[]/~|\?.<,"];
NSString *dbFilename = [[name componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:chss] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

if(aDicItem.mediaType == 1){
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageThumb, 1.0) writeToFile: filePath atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"file path = %@",filePath);


}



//Return file path
return filePath;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

For those looking for Eddy's answer in Objective-C.

## import

- (void)insertImage:(UIImage *)image intoAlbumNamed:(NSString *)albumName {
  //Fetch a collection in the photos library that has the title "albumNmame"
  PHAssetCollection *collection = [self fetchAssetCollectionWithAlbumName: albumName];

  if (collection == nil) {
      //If we were unable to find a collection named "albumName" we'll create it before inserting the image
      [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
          [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle: albumName];
      } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          if (error != nil) {
              NSLog(@"Error inserting image into album: %@", error.localizedDescription);
          }

  ```
      if (success) {
          //Fetch the newly created collection (which we *assume* exists here)
          PHAssetCollection *newCollection = [self fetchAssetCollectionWithAlbumName:albumName];
          [self insertImage:image intoAssetCollection: newCollection];
      }
  }];
  ```

  } else {
      //If we found the existing AssetCollection with the title "albumName", insert into it
      [self insertImage:image intoAssetCollection: collection];
  }
  }
- (PHAssetCollection *)fetchAssetCollectionWithAlbumName:(NSString *)albumName {
  PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
  //Provide the predicate to match the title of the album.
  fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"title == '%@'", albumName]];

  //Fetch the album using the fetch option
  PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:fetchOptions];

  //Assuming the album exists and no album shares it's name, it should be the only result fetched
  return fetchResult.firstObject;
  }